# How to improve a sliding miter saw dust collection?

Tags: sawdust, dust-collection, miter-saw

I have a sliding miter saw with a seriously undersized dust port (1¼").  It's originally built to throw the dust in a tiny bag. When ever I make cuts, about 25% (bag) or 50% (shopvac) of the dust is collected and the rest just spread in a conical way.

How can I improve dust collection so that it captures a lot more dust?  Are there generic accessories available to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Most miter saws don't have very good dust collection. You can [buy](http://www.fastcap.com/estore/pc/ChopShop-Saw-Hood-p113.htm) or [build](http://www.oneprojectcloser.com/how-to-make-compound-miter-saw-dust-hood/) a hood to catch the dust.

[image: FastCap ChopShop hood]

([Source](http://www.fastcap.com/estore/pc/ChopShop-Saw-Hood-p113.htm))

[image: Homemade miter saw hood with dust collection]

([Source](http://forums.finewoodworking.com/fine-woodworking-knots/general-discussion/miter-saw-hood-and-ras-hood))

Some hoods can be connected to your dust collector, while others funnel the dust down into a bucket.

Answer (score 7):

I tend to agree that compound miters have horrible dust collection design.  Mostly I've given up, even though I have hose connected to my dust collector.

My dust collector doesn't have enough static pressure and the little port tends to get clogged.  I'm sure that this is one tool the Shop-Vac actually works much better on.

However, I do have one possible recommendation if you have a dust collector and the willingness to set this up.  There is a [dust hood](http://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B0000223WV/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1)  (this one is 13" x 16")
[image]

You can set one of these behind the saw and it should catch a much larger % of sawdust from the miter.  It can cover an area and the saw will be sending most of the dust right at the hood.  I have two of these, one for my lathe and another where I use my belt sander.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the time to try a DIY solution, Fisher's Shop on YouTube had a different approach which doesn't require lots of space or material. It mounts directly to the back fence on the mitre saw. He claims some pretty high dust collection rates up in the range of 90%+.

Unless you have the same saw you will have to make some minor modifications but his video should serve as a good guide.

**Reference link:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrBaHKtz8GQ

**Example picture:**

[image]